# Changing date format Prestashop backoffice to DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: prestashop, datetimepicker, prestashop-1.7

I want to change the date format Prestashop using in BackOffice especially in `Edit product > quality tab > available date`, from YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY. I managed to do it in javascript but in the ps_product table I want it to keep the YYYY-MM-DD format because Prestashop validate dates in Validate.php class and I don't want to touch core files.

The library used is datetimepicker and the `format` option doesn't support toDisplay and toValue as the datepicker library.

Any idea to do so?

Comment: No, you really don't. You want to change the display settings only. Dates have no format in PHP, JavaScript and MySQL. All three have Date or DateTime types. Formats apply only to **strings** - when parsing a string into a DateTime or formatting a DateTime into a string for display.  Using strings instead of dates results in bugs or worse, bad data. What is `04-07`? April 7 or July 4th? You have **no** way of knowing. And no way to properly sort those strings. Dates on the other hand can be sorted without problem

Comment: `I managed to do it in javascript` you have to remove the buggy code now. Most likely, all you need to do is change a configuration setting to tell the application which locale or date format to use

Answer (score 0):

The format of the dates displayed in Prestashop is tied to the Language configuration.
The language chosen depends on the one defined for the backoffice admin user or the one chosen by the customers / visitors.
Assuming you are on Prestashop 1.7.x, this can be changed under:
Backoffice > International > Localization > Language tab.